# How to setup Adobe Analytics in webapp react typescript using Experience Platform Launch

Tags: reactjs, typescript, adobe-analytics, adobe-launch

How to setup Adobe Analytics in web app react typescript using Experience Platform Launch?

I have just js scripts like this:
`<SCRIPT src="//assets.adobedtm.com/<hash>-staging.js"></SCRIPT>`
and
 `<script type="text/javascript">_satellite.pageBottom();</script>`

So, the question is how I can implement page tracking using those two scripts?
I want to create a component to track page switching when users walkthrough

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Launch, go into the property that you want to release. Then Go to the Environments:

[image]

It will give you the script to deploy:

[image]

Once you've deployed and tested the deployments, you can make a rule in Launch. In the rule, you set up triggers, conditions and actions. [This](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/analytics-learn/tutorials/implementation/spa-pages/using-best-practices-when-tracking-spa.html?lang=en) explains it well.